# Next.js: one page that match root '/' and dynamic route '/param'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a website as a single page that is using Next.js. I have the home page on route `/` that show a list of products. The code of this page is located in `pages/index.js`. Each product has an `id` so I can jump to it using `/#product-id`.

To make it more url friendly I replicate this behaviour using the `product-id` as a second param in the route like that: `/product-id`.

What I do is simply looking on the `product-id` param using `useRouter()`:

```js
const selectedProductId = useRouter().query['product-id']
```

And then scroll to the element with this id using `js`:

```js
document.getElementById(selectedProductId ).scrollIntoView()
```

So I to change my script name from `/pages/index.js` to `/pages/[product-id].js`.

So now the route `/1234` work has expected but if I go to `/` I get error 404.

So has someone an idea how I can match `/` and `/param` using one `js` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nextjs has file system based routing, so if you remove `/pages/index.js` of course you will get an `404` error. Also `/pages/index.js` and `/pages/[product-id].js` will render two separate pages.

To answer your question, if it is possible to match two routes like `/` and `/[productId]` in one file using nextjs I don't think that is possible however similar results can be achieved by using shallow routing specific to your use case.

So for your use case, I suggest using shallow routing unless you want to render the same component in both pages just to get the `product-id` or want to make use of hash URLs.

You can make `product-id` a query string parameter and update it using shallow-routing. Here is an example,

Keep `/pages/index.js`

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const router = useRouter()

// when want to change the productId call
router.push('/?productId=1234', undefined, { shallow: true })

// call the scrollToView inside a useEffect hook
useEffect(() => {
    const productId = router.query.productId
    // get the element using the productId above then call scrollIntoView()
})

// if using useEffect with the dependency router.query.productId, 
// when you change the productId once and scroll up and try to change to the same -
// productId again it will not scroll to view, hence not using the dependency array
// at all
```

#### To explain more on what shallow routing does

Shallow routing will allow the change of URL without running the data fetching methods i.e `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` again. Which will make the updated query and pathname available without changing the state. Read more about it [nextjs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing).

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation  I will finally just use a simple query's param like `/?product-id=123`

Comment: Great, let me know if you had any problems implementing it.

Comment: It is possible by using double brackets: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/dynamic-api-routes

Answer (score 4):

Optional catch all routes

Catch all routes can be made optional by including the parameter in double brackets ([[...slug]]).

Comment: This is the answer! A file `pages/[[...slug]].js` will catch all routes, and then you don't need `index.js` at all.

Comment: 100%, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: Extract the shared code

You could extract a Page component to a separate file and then import it in both `/pages/index.js` and `/pages/[product-id].js`, so the code is not duplicated.

### Option 2: Use experimental `rewrites` feature

Assuming you have `/pages/[product-id].js` you can show this page when a user requests `/`.

You would need to add `next.config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    async rewrites() {
      return [
        { source: "/", destination: "/[product-id]" },
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

So, when a user requests `/` they would see the content of `/[product-id]`, just with the empty product id.

Note, that at the moment rewrite doesn't support auto-rendered dynamic pages, so you **have to disable auto-rendering for the dynamic page**.

You can do that by adding `getServerSideProps` to `/pages/[product-id].js`.

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  return {
    props: {},
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great idea. Unfortunately I don't think to use it for now since it's experimental ;) But I'm really excited to use it in the future