# I want to make route as params also with without params - next js

Tags: javascript, next.js, routes

I have a NEXTJS project and I Use SSR to fetch data, but I want to make such thing:

When users are on the "/" route, I show them a random product detail page, but when they search for some product and click on it, they should be redirected to eg '/product-01'.

I know how I can take random products, don't think about that, I have a problem with routes, I want to make this route functional on one page.js file

finally, the question is: how can use the next js route if the route param is just empty?

Answer (score 0):

In Nextjs is you check for a router parameter if it exists then it will return you value of the param or it param does not exists then it will return `undefined`. for example
suppose we have product=productname
then we will check `router.query.product`
if url have that perameter than will be return productname
if not than it will return undefined so you can place check of `undefined` to check empty parameter case.

Comment: Yes, I tried this logic, but [product].js expects parameters from the user, if the parameters are empty it will show me a 404 error

Comment: I resolve this problem with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62100121/next-js-one-page-that-match-root-and-dynamic-route-param